# Hierarchy / Flyweight / Instancing Problem in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns

Here is the problem I am trying to solve, (I have simplified the actual problem, but this should give you all the relevant information). I have a hierarchy like so:

```
1.A
1.B
1.C
2.A
3.D
4.B
5.F
```

(This is hard to illustrate - each number is the parent, each letter is the child).

1. Creating an instance of the 'letter' objects is expensive (IO, database costs, etc), so should only be done once.
2. The hierarchy needs to be easy to navigate.
3. Children in the hierarchy need to have just one parent.
4. Modifying the contents of the letter objects should be possible directly from the objects in the hierarchy.
5. There needs to be a central store containing all of the 'letter' objects (and only those in the hierarchy).
6. 'letter' and 'number' objects need to be possible to create from a constructor (such as Letter(**kwargs) ).
7. It is perfectably acceptable to expect that when a letter changes from the hierarchy, all other letters will respect the same change.

Hope this isn't too abstract to illustrate the problem.

What would be the best way of solving this? (Then I'll post my solution)

Here's an example script:

```
one = Number('one')
a = Letter('a')
one.addChild(a)
two = Number('two')
a = Letter('a')
two.addChild(a)

for child in one:
    child.method1()
for child in two:
    print '%s' % child.method2()
```

Comment: How is this a hierarchy?  It looks like a simple association between the "number" and the "letter".

Comment: Again I'm only trying to show you a subset of the problem (it is actually a hierarchy like 1.A.B.C.D), because the actual data is a lot more complex than this, application-specific and would take a lot of work to explain, so I'm trying to present this abstracted from the irrelevant complexities.

Comment: Could you write a sentence or two of background information about the actual problem domain. I fear that you have made the question so abstract that people find it hard to make sense of it.

Comment: Agreed, maybe it is too abstract, sometimes it's hard to define the problem without confusing with the actual details (and my company wouldn't allow it). It was still useful to hear people's thoughts to help refine my own though...

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach will use builtin data types. If I get your drift, the `Letter` object should be created by a factory with a `dict` cache to keep previously generated `Letter` objects. The factory will create only one `Letter` object for each key.

A `Number` object can be a sub-class of `list` that will hold the `Letter` objects, so that `append()` can be used to add a child. A `list` is easy to navigate.

A crude outline of a caching factory:

```
>>> class Letters(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.cache = {}
...     def create(self, v):
...         l = self.cache.get(v, None)
...         if l:
...             return l
...         l = self.cache[v] = Letter(v)
...         return l
>>> factory=Letters()
>>> factory.cache
{}
>>> factory.create('a')
<__main__.Letter object at 0x00EF2950>
>>> factory.create('a')
<__main__.Letter object at 0x00EF2950>
>>>
```

To fulfill requirement 6 (constructor), here is
a more contrived example, using `__new__`, of a caching constructor. This is similar to [Recipe 413717: Caching object creation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413717/) .

```
class Letter(object):
    cache = {}

    def __new__(cls, v):
        o = cls.cache.get(v, None)
        if o:
            return o
        else:
            o = cls.cache[v] = object.__new__(cls)
            return o

    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        self.refcount = 0

    def addAsChild(self, chain):
        if self.refcount > 0:
            return False
        self.refcount += 1
        chain.append(self)
        return True
```

Testing the cache functionality

```
>>> l1 = Letter('a')
>>> l2 = Letter('a')
>>> l1 is l2
True
>>>
```

For enforcing a single parent, you'll need a method on `Letter` objects (not `Number`) - with a reference counter. When called to perform the addition it will refuse addition if the counter is greater than zero.

```
l1.addAsChild(num4)
```

Comment: for 6, you can easily hide a factory behind any callable. Are you sure about the constructor requirement?

Comment: Cool, that's more like how I've ended up implementing it, so sounds like I'm on the right lines. One thing I found though - the __init__ is always executed after the __new__ (regardless if it returns an existing object), which is fine in this instance, but what if the __init__ does a lot more?

Comment: Have __init__ check for presence of a flag - how about refcount?